# C# / ASP.NET Web Application MVC Submitting a File and Reading the Text From It

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been working on this and searching the web exhaustively, none of the solutions I've come across seem to match what I need or work in the way it seems they ought to.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.  I've created an ASP.NET Web Application and I've created multiple exercises that are connected to it using an ExerciseController.   The last few ones I need to make though require a file that is uploaded.   I do this using my existing form which looks like so:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("CountWord", "Exercises")" method="post">
<input type="text" name="findWord" value="@if (Model != null) {@Model.findWord}" /><br /><br />

<input name="file" type="file" /><br />

<p>
    <label>Result: </label><input type="number" name="total" value="@if (Model != null) {@Model.total}" disabled />
</p><br />
<button type="submit">Count Words</button>
```

Now at this point, pressing that button should pull it in to the PostModel I have written for it.  This is where things get a little fuzzy for me.  I've tried a lot of different options and eventually this is the point I've reached:

```
public class CountWordPostModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload { get; set; }
    public string text;
    public string findWord { get; set; }        
}
```

I've tried multiple times to try and get information from the file inside of the ViewModel, but nothing seemed to work.  Any time I tried to reference it the variable did not seem accessible there.   So instead I moved on over to my ExerciseController where I have it defined.

```
public ActionResult CountWord(CountWordPostModel model)
    {
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(model.fileUpload.InputStream);
        string text = stream.ReadToEnd();
        var word = model.findWord;
        var wordinator = new Wordinator(text);

        var result = new CountWordViewModel
        {
            text = text, findWord = word,
            total = wordinator.CountWord(word)
        };

        return View(result);
    }
```

The problem here is it tells me that the file is null.  Which naturally it should not be because it should only get this far if it has been submitted.

Any ideas as to what's going wrong or an easier way to do this would certainly be appreciated.  I've been banging my head against a figurative wall for a while now.

Comment: A first observation to make is that your input has name "file", while model field is "fileUpload". They should match

Comment: The field name in your HTML view is `file`, but your view model's field is called `fileUpload`.

Comment: Also, while it won't affect functionality, the idiomatic way to write public member names in C# is to use camel-casing. So try `FileUpload` instead of `fileUpload`, `Total` instead of `total`, etc. I know from experience that code assumed to be private forever has a way of ending up not so, and it makes life easier when sharing code if you abide by the same widely-used presentational conventions as other programmers.

Comment: I fixed the file to fileUpload issue, but it still throws a null error at the end even after that.   Thanks for catching that though.  Must have changed it in one of my other "attempts" to fix it and forgotten to update that part.

Comment: @FadedAce, oh yeah, you also need to add attribute ` enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form, see [this tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/) for reference

Comment: Ah-hah!  @Andrei, thank you so much!  I missed that completely.  That fixed it.

Comment: Instead of `StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(model.fileUpload.InputStream);` try `using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(model.fileUpload.InputStream)) { ...// rest of your code }` Since StreamReader implements IDisposable you should use a `using` block on the variable `stream`. That way `.Dispose()` is automatically called for you, which will clean up any used resources.